# MobX makeAutoObservable does not create actions

Tags: mobx, mobx-react-lite

I have a MobX-Store setup with `makeAutoObservable(this)`. I would expect this to mark the methods that write to observable state as actions. Yet that does not seem to be the case. Here's what I did:

I created the following class:

```
class ModalState {

  opened = false

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  open() {
    this.opened = true
  }
}

let modalState: ModalState

export function getModalState() {
  if (!modalState)
    modalState = new ModalState()
  return modalState
}
```

Then I try to use it to control my modal like this:

```
const MyModal = observer(() => {

  const [modalState] = useState(() => getModalState())

  return (
    <Modal opened={modalState.opened} onClose={modalState.close}>
      ...
    </Modal>
  )
})
```

However, this invocation of `modalState.close` does not count as an action, which I know because the modal does not actually close when I click the close button. To fix it, I have to change the class like this:

```
const MyModal = observer(() => {

  const [modalState] = useState(() => getModalState())

  const close = action(() => modalState.close())
  return (
    <Modal opened={modalState.opened} onClose={close}>
      ...
    </Modal>
  )
})
```

Which works, but then what is the point of `makeAutoObservable`? I thought I could mark methods of the store as actions, so that I can then use them as normal in the rest of my code without having to wrap them in actions every time I want the store to change.

Is there a way to make actions on a store invokable directly, like the first version of `MyModal`?

Comment: Switching to arrow functions fixes the problem, but I don't really understand why. I was not getting any errors about this being undefined, and I also don't see why that would change by wrapping the calls in action().

Comment: It's not a MobX problem, it's just how JS `this` works, it might be very confusing at the start. When you have `dot` call, e.g. `.close()` it preserves `this` so you can use it without an arrow function. `action` has nothing to do with it, you can remove it and it will work too. But if you pass it like that without the call `onClose={modalState.close}`, you basically pass it without `this` now. `this` only preserves when you call the function right away with `dot`. Hope it makes sense, but I recommend you to read about `this` in general.